# Understanding the State Monad

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, state-monad, newtype

I am learning about the State monad in the book "Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!" by Miran Lipovaca. 
For the following monad instance:

```
instance Monad (State s) where 
   return x = State $ \s -> (x,s)
   (State h) >>= f = State $ \s -> let (a, newState) = h s
                                       (State g) = f a
                                   in g newState
```

I am having trouble understanding the definition for the `>>=` function. I am not sure whether `h` is the stateful computation (i.e. the function that takes a state and returns a result with an updated state) or whether it is a state. I am guessing that it must be a stateful computation since it is applied to the state (of type `s`) in the lambda function to produce the result `(a, newState)`.

But from the type declaration of `State s a`:

```
newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a,s) }
```

The state is of type `s` and the result is of type `a`. So for the monad instance, is the `s` in `instance Monad (State s)` the *type* of the state or is it actually the stateful computation? Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: using `newtype {- StatePassingComputations -} State s a = MkState { runState :: s -> (a,s) }` would've probably been a lot less confusing, in a newbies--oriented book.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A `State` object does *not* store a state. It stores a "change of state". Indeed it stores a function `runState :: s -> (a, s)`. Here `s` is the type of the state, and `a` is the type of the "output" so to speak.

The function thus takes the state as input, and returns a 2-tuple `(a, s)`. Here the first item is the "output", and the second item is the "new state". The new state might be the same as the old state, but one thus has the opportunity to make changes to the state (otherwise it is not very useful to use a `State` anyway).

We can bind `State`-changing object and a "factory" of a state changing object (`a -> State s b`) together in a new `State`-changing object. We thus construct a function that takes an initial state `s0`. We first run that to the `runState` of the `State` object, and thus retrieve a 2-tuple `(a, s1)`. We can then use this `a` to construct a `State s b` object, and then we run the (altered state) `s1` through the `runState` of that `State` object.

A more verbose implementation is thus:

```
instance Monad (State s) where 
   return x = State $ \s -> (x,s)
   (State h) >>= f = State g
       where g s0 = (b, s2) -- result of second runState
                 where (a, s1) = h s0 -- run through first runState
                       -- create second state with the output of the first
                       State f' = f a
                       (b, s2) = f' s1 -- run through second runState
```

Note that we here never actually *have* a state value. We only construct a new function that *will* work on that state value.

Schematically we could see the bind operator as follows:

```
  s0
\    /
 |  |
 |  |
 ||||
  |\_________
  |          '
  |           s1
  v         \    /
  a ----->   |  |
             |  |
             ||||
              |\_______
              |        '
              v        s2
              b
```

So here the first `runState` takes the initial state `s0` will return an `a` and `s1`. With the `a`, we construct a new `runState`, that can then process the state `s1` further, and will return a `b` and the new state `s2`.